# Fatal error: Class 'JDatabaseDriver' not found

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
Fatal error: Class 'JDatabaseDriver' not found in /home/jensen/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php on line 631
```

I have been searching online for a answer to this problem for two days now.I have spent a lot of time on the joomla forums, but I have not found anything address this issue. Hopefully I can get some direction here.

This error appears when I go to the website http://jensenlocksmithing.com

However, if I type in http:/jensenlocksmithing.com/index.php the error disappears again. That seems really strange to me.

Here's the code block the error is referring to:

/**
     * Create an database object
     *
     * @return  JDatabaseDriver
     *
     * @see     JDatabaseDriver
     * @since   11.1
     */
    protected static function createDbo()
    {
        $conf = self::getConfig();

```
    $host = $conf->get('host');
    $user = $conf->get('user');
    $password = $conf->get('password');
    $database = $conf->get('db');
    $prefix = $conf->get('dbprefix');
    $driver = $conf->get('dbtype');
    $debug = $conf->get('debug');

    $options = array('driver' => $driver, 'host' => $host, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'database' => $database, 'prefix' => $prefix);

    try
    {
        $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($options);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException $e)
    {
        if (!headers_sent())
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        }

        jexit('Database Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $db->setDebug($debug);

    return $db;
}
```

I have tried to completely reinstall the joomla installation to fix the problem, and I cleared my cache after, but I still receive the error.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, it is what I used in my Coppermine Photo Gallery image module:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$option = array();
$option['driver']   = $config->get('dbtype');
$option['host']     = $config->get('host');
$option['user']     = $config->get('user');
$option['password'] = $config->get('password');
$option['database'] = $config->get('db');
$option['prefix']   = $config->get('dbprefix');

//UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO VIEW OPTIONS ARRAY CONTENTS         
//print_r($option);

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try
{
    $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage());
    $db->setDebug($debug);
    return false;
}
return $db;
```

Hopefully that gets your problem resolved.